# saving to and reading from mysql with php arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to determine the best way to store, update, read the following info in a database. right now i have a very inflexible solution that will not work moving forward. here's the scenario:

our website has an ever growing list of "talks". each talk has a title, description, unspecified number of bullet points, category (multi, from a specific list of categories), 1 or more speakers (who have names, institutions, and image files) and a few more irrelevant fields.

my trouble is with the variable information: bullet points (an array that i can serialize?), speakers (an array of arrays, not sure what to do here), and category.

I'm really looking for information on how to best format the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common solution is - every object must be a table. Then this tables is related by some id  values of every type of object. Example: In the class a lot of pupils. So Table Class and table Pupil. One pupil can be only in one class but in one class a lot of Pupils :), so Relation can be made by Pupil table with class_id field.

To read and write from database, best practices is to use PDO or AdoDB library., they will help you a lot.

Comment: i was thinking multiple tables would be the solution for the speaker information, it's just not built that way right now, so it's a big change to correct everything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can't create other tables so as to use the common solution described by @Anton, right?

If you need to store as array you could use [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) or [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to store your arrays as strings.

EDIT:

Then to after the read the strings you change them back to their original form with [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) or [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (depending which way you decided to go)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use JSON encoded string for this.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php